# L'hopital's rule on exponents that give same derivative?

Tags: limits

For finding the limit of sequences when n tends to infinity,

for example, this sequence: $$3^n\over (3^n + 2^n)$$

I know that the limit is 1, as 2^n is negligible in comparison to 3^n as n tends to infinity.

But how can I mathematically show that it really does converge to a number?

I tried using L'hopital rule but differentiating gives the same result!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need L'Hopital's rule, just divide numerator and denominator by $3^n$ and simplify.  Note that $(2/3)^n\to 0 $ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: Ah..thank you. Actually I have tried that before, but I think I have overlooked 2^n / 3^n, and simplified back to the original equation... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\frac{3^n}{3^n + 2^n} = \frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n}$$

Thus
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n}{3^n + 2^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n} = 1$$